# why css class not applied in checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I make a simple demo in which markup or HTML is same .But in one markup one extra rule applied and other it is not applied why ?
Mark Up :

```html
<div class="rc40w1 oform oform-initialized">
  <div class="rc40w5 hide">
    <div class="rc40w3">
      <ul class="chk-ul oform-w1 ovalid rc40open">
        <li>
          <label for="5A0B0A9213D344628F4BBA4029291F4E">
            <input type="checkbox"
              id="5A0B0A9213D344628F4BBA4029291F4E"
              name="5A0B0A9213D344628F4BBA4029291F4E"
              value="5A0B0A9213D344628F4BBA4029291F4E"
              class=" ">
            <span class="obox"></span>
            <span class="rc40label">
              Infrastructure
              </span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Example 1 : Here is my code

https://jsbin.com/supateketa/3/edit?html,css,output
[image]

If you see in `class="obox"` before psedo element have only one class see screenshot.

**In Second Example**
IF YOU SEE EXTRA class is added `:root input+.obox:before` why ?

https://jsbin.com/hovaxakeba/edit?html,css,output

[image]

why it is not added in first example ?

curious to know why in one case it added and in another case it not.

```
:root input+.obox:before {
    position: relative;
    left: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share how you set css styles for your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If improper css selector is added , then the particular style block gets ignored.

In first example you have added `_:-ms-input-placeholder` selector before `:root input+.obox:before` selector. I think it's a improper selector. Thats why this style is not applied in your first example.